# git pull one file from remote

Tags: git, git-pull

I've cloned a repository "Rep" and created my own local branch "Li".
I've committed a file called "task.js" to the local "Li" branch and pushed it to the remote "Li" branch.
Now I want to revert this action by:

1. pulling the original "task.js" from the remote "master" branch to
   the local "Li" branch
2. push the reverted "task.js" from the local "Li" branch to the remote "Li" branch.

I tried to read several "pull" tutorials but can't figure out a way to do this (maybe because I don't really understand the basics yet...)

Thanks,
Li

Comment: Could you be more specific about your commit history? What branch does Li based on? Is your local master tracking you remote master? Better with a commit history graph.

Comment: I don't know how to produce such a graph, and it will probably just confuse you since I have more stuff there, but: I started by cloning the repository, this created the default local master branch, right? then I created a new branch called "Li" which originated from the local master branch. And then I pushed this branch to the remote repo, thus creating a remote "Li" branch. Please guide me if I need to be even more specific, I'm new to Git...

Comment: Which means there is already a task.js in your master branch which is exactly same with the one in the remote master, right? What your are tring to do is simply overwirte the wrong task.js with the one in master, am I understand correct?

Comment: Yes, thanks. sorry for having trouble to explain this. I have other changes I would like to keep though, I just want to revert this specific file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git reset HEAD~` will revert the laster commit of the current branch, but since you have already pushed the branch Li to public, it is better to do a `git checkout master task.js` and commit again in your branch Li.

Comment: what does this command do? Does this overrides the local "Li" task.js with the local master task.js? (it worked, I just want to understand what I did)

Comment: Yes, `git checkout master task.js` will simply checkout the task.js of the master branch, for your case, you probably need a `-f` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You just simply revert a tom first commit using below command,

**git reset HEAD^1**

Then then push the changes to remote branch.

Comment: Due to he his already pushed the Li branch which means this is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Oh, ok, so he need to revert that commit.